# Testing Upload scalar type in graphql-playground

Tags: php, graphql, api-platform.com, mutation, graphql-playground

Ex:

```
mutation {
  uploadMediaObject(input: {file: "C:/Users/ASUS/Pictures/bmw.png"}) {
   mediaObject {id contentUrl}
  }
}
```

I want to test that mutation using graphql playground. So how to put a file in there?

Comment: [Hope it will help you](https://moonhighway.com/how-the-upload-scalar-works)

Answer (score 1):

I found out that neither GraphiQL nor GraphQL Playground support file upload.
So my solution is using [Altair](https://altair.sirmuel.design/)

Comment: Maybe tell us how then